# Seeking a combinatorial proof of $2n^{n-3} = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{m-1}m^{m-2}(n-m)^{n-m-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, cayley-graphs

I need to prove the following using Combinatorial proof: (Not using math laws But finding two similar Combinatorial problems)

$$2n^{n-3} = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{m-1}m^{m-2}(n-m)^{n-m-2}$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ozBAm.png))

---

**I was told that solving another problem may help, So I solved it and here it is.**

The number of undirected trees with n vertices such that the edge 1-2 doesn't exist is: $(n-2)*n^{n-3}$.

Comment: So the number of undirected trees with $n$ vertices such that the edge $12$ *does* exist is...?

Comment: It's $n^{n-2} - (n-2)*n^{n-3}$

Comment: How does that help, It's similar to what's written above but not exactly the same.

Comment: $n^{n-2} - (n-2)n^{n-3} = n^{n-3}(n - (n-2)) = 2n^{n-3}$.

Comment: That not what is written on the right side, plus this isn't a Combinatorial proof

Comment: On the right hand side, you have a different way of counting the number of undirected edges with $n$ vertices containing the edge $12$. If you find it, you get the combinatorial proof you wanted.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't know what you mean by "On the right hand side, you have a different way of counting the number of undirected edges with  vertices containing the edge 12" may you give some hint...

Comment: I think @MishaLavrov made a typo. If you replace the word “edges” with “trees”, the whole sentence makes sense.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217386/177399

Answer (score 1):

As @MishaLavrov mentioned in the comments, both sides are different ways of counting the number of undirected trees with $n$ vertices containing the edge $1-2$.

We collect the results:

Number of undirected trees with $k$ vertices: $f(k) =: k^{k-2}$.

Number of undirected trees with $n$ vertices containing the edge $1-2$: $g(k) =: 2k^{k-3}$.

Now, on your right hand side, imagine breaking your tree of $n$ vertices into two trees: one with $m$ vertices, and one with $n-m$ vertices. Now apply $f(k)$ on those two trees, and sum over all possible values of $m$.

Comment: I can't understand why "Number of undirected trees with  vertices containing the edge..." Plus I think you mean k and not n